# create some list for n number of person from the list of multiple person's attributes in Python

Tags: python

I have some lists describe some attribute of 'n' number of person( say person-1, person-2, ..... person-n), like following type of lists (**according to attribute**):

```
name_list= ["alex", "sam", "name-n"]
roll_list= ["1", "2", "roll-n"]
email_list= ["alex@gmail.com", "sam@gmail.com", "email-n"]
```

Now I need to create another n number of lists **according to person** like this:

```
person-1 = ["alex", "1", "alex@gmail.com"]
person-2 = ["sam", "2", "sam@gmail.com"]
person-n = ["name-n", "roll-n", "email-n"]
```

How can I code for this in `python`?

Comment: yeah, sorry for the mistake. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
person_dict = {f'person-{n+1}' : [name, roll, email] for n, (name, roll, email) in enumerate(zip(name_list, roll_list, email_list))}
```

**Output** :

`person_dict` would be :

```
{
    'person-1': ['alex', '1', 'alex@gmail.com'],
    'person-2': ['sam', '2', 'sam@gmail.com'],
    'person-3': ['name-n', 'roll-n', 'email-n']
}
```

In this way, you won't have `n` number of different variables assigned to their corresponding list, but you'll have one dictionary and you can look up keys from that dictionary with `person_dict.get(key)`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `zip`:

```
>>> people = [*zip(name_list, roll_list, email_list)]
>>> people
[('alex', '1', 'alex@gmail.com'),
 ('sam', '2', 'sam@gmail.com'),
 ('name-n', 'roll-n', 'email-n')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a 2d array:

```py
people = [[name_list[i], roll_list[i], email_list[i]] for i in range(len(name_list))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible without hyphen, there is such a way:

```
class Dict(object):
    pass

for n, (name, roll, email) in enumerate(zip(name_list, roll_list, email_list)):
    setattr(Dict, 'person' + str(n), [name, roll, email])

Dict.person1 # ['alex', '1', 'alex@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

name_list= ["alex", "sam", "name-n"]
roll_list= ["1", "2", "roll-n"]
email_list= ["alex@gmail.com", "sam@gmail.com", "email-n"]

for index in range(len(name_list)):
 exec("person_%s = [name_list[index], roll_list[index], email_list[index]]" %(index+1))
print(person_1)
print(person_2)
print(person_3)
Output:
['alex', '1', 'alex@gmail.com']
['sam', '2', 'sam@gmail.com']
['name-n', 'roll-n', 'email-n']